# Error while importing sql - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, innodb, import

I am trying to import an sql file which shows me the following error:

```
Error
SQL query:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `users` (

 `uid` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `uemail` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `upassword` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uname` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uemailh` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uclass` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `regno` VARCHAR( 8 ) NOT NULL ,
 `absencecount` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'a:10:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;}',
 `internalmarks` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  's:73:"["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]";',
PRIMARY KEY (  `uid` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `uemail` (  `uemail` ,  `uname` ) ,
KEY  `regno` (  `regno` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =2;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I've tried to create a new  database in my local machine everything works fine. But, while importing it in the remote server it shows the above error. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html):

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables.

My guess would be the character set you are using in conjunction with

```
UNIQUE KEY  `uemail` (  `uemail` ,  `uname` ) ,
```

Please note that both of those columns are VARCHAR(255). Together their maximum character length could be 511 (255 characters X 2 + 1 byte for VARCHAR length management). Since UTF8 is a multibyte character set, 511 * 2 = 1022. That's way past InnoDB's limit of 767 bytes. Even if you convert the table to MyISAM, it's still past 1000 bytes.

I would suggest drastically reducing the widths of `uemail` and  `uname`.

Comment: But, that works in my local machine...

Comment: Your remote machine and local machine are evidently using two different default charsets.